# Regex to extract the content inside [squarebrackets] but not [[wiki-links]]

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-negation

I'm looking for a regex that could match and extract the content inside `[squarebrackets]` but not inside `[[wiki-links]]`. So for the example above, I would extract only the `squarebrackets` part, but not `[squarebrackets]`, `[wiki-links]`, or `wiki-links`.

Currently, I found two regexes:

1. Extracts the content inside [[wiki-links]] only (and not [squarebrackets]):

```
/[^[\]]+(?=]])/g
```

2. Extracts the content inside both [[wiki-links]] and [squarebrackets]:

```
\[[^\[\]]+\]/g
```

The 2nd one is close to what I want, but it still includes the squarebrackets themselves and catches [[wiki-links]] content which I don't want.

How could I exclude those by modifying the regex expression, so that I only get the content inside the single squarebrackets, without the brackets themselves?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `(?<!\[)\[([^\[\]]+)\](?!\])`? See https://regex101.com/r/mkhCX7/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is super close, but can we also exclude the `[` and the the `]` from the result? :)

Comment: But you just capture the part in between `[` and `]`, they will get excluded.

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew replying in the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?<!\[)\[([^[\]]+)](?!])/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkhCX7/2). *Details*:

- `(?<!\[)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a `[` char
- `\[`  - a `[` char
- `([^[\]]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(?!])` - a `]` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "I'm looking for a regex that could match and extract the content inside [squarebrackets] but not inside [[wiki-links]].";
const regex = /(?<!\[)\[([^[\]]+)](?!])/g;
const matches = Array.from(text.matchAll(regex), x => x[1]);
console.log(matches);
```

And in case you use it with an old ECMAScript regex flavor:

```js
var text = "I'm looking for a regex that could match and extract the content inside [squarebrackets] but not inside [[wiki-links]].";
var regex = /(\[?)\[([^[\]]+)](?!])/g;
var matches = [], m;
while (m = regex.exec(text)) {
  if (m[1] !== undefined) {
    matches.push(m[2]);
  }
}
console.log(matches);
```